# Recyclerview inside ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-recyclerview

so I have ExpandableListView that gets its data from server via json..
now the parents and children are arrays, so.. I receive a list of orders and within each order there's a list meals..! so we need a recyclerview for the orders and another recyclerview for the meals..!

Right now I'm using this [library](https://github.com/SilenceDut/ExpandableLayout), so I have xml file that have two views one for the header (parent) and another below it for the meal (child) and it's a cardview, now in the activity that will display the expandablelistview there's a one recycler which displays the a list of the orders successfully..!

But how can I make a recyclerview for the children, should I just add another recyclerview below the first one... or what..!? what would you do in this case..!?